# Program to find HCF(Highest Common factor) of 2 unsigned integers in C

Tags: c

The following is a program for above stated purposes. It is working for equal numbers or the numbers which are the direct multiples of each-other. But when that is not the case, it is giving some weird output. I am not able to find the logical bug. Can any1 help me?(The program is compiled and run in MVS 2019 Community Edition).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void calculateHCF(unsigned int* number1, unsigned int* number2, unsigned int* HCF)
{
    if (*number1 % *number2 == 0)
        *HCF = *number2;
    else if (*number2 % *number1 == 0)
        * HCF = *number1;
    else if (*number1 > *number2)
    {
        unsigned int* divisor = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));

        for (*divisor = *number2 / 2; *divisor >= 2; *divisor--)
        {
            if (*number1 % *divisor == 0 && *number2 % *divisor == 0)
            {
                *HCF = *divisor;
                break;
            }
            else;
        }
        //free(divisor);
    }
    else
    {
        unsigned int* divisor = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));

        for (*divisor = *number1 / 2; *divisor >=2; *divisor--)
        {
            if (*number1 % *divisor == 0 && *number2 % *divisor == 0)
            {
                *HCF = *divisor;
                break;
            }
            else;
        }
        //free(divisor);
    }


}
int main()
{
    unsigned int * number1 = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int* number2 = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    unsigned int* HCF = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    printf("\nThis program prints the HCF of the two numbers entered.");
    printf("\nEnter the two numbers : ");
    scanf("%u %u", number1, number2);
    calculateHCF(number1, number2, HCF);
    printf("\nThis HCF of %u and %u is : %u.\n", *number1, *number2, *HCF);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[HCF wrong output when the 2 numbers are not the direct multiples of eachother](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJTX.jpg)

Comment: *You don't need all of those pointers.*  If you eliminate the pointers, you won't need *any* of the mallocs.

Comment: The picture you posted looks like an underflow.

Comment: I am using the pointers just because I want to practice more pointers. Please bear with me. :)

Comment: Practice *correctly.*

Comment: @Robert Harvey How to do that ? And why the use of pointers is wrong? And where ?

Comment: By using pointers where they are appropriate.

Comment: The function should take two integer values and return an integer result.  If you can't return the value, only the result should be a pointer, but that's a misdesign.  You should use Euvlid’s algorithm — it is the world's oldest algorithm. You then don't need to have the two halves of the function; it works fine whether a > b or a < b or a == b.  This is not a sensible way of practicing with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`*divisor--` decrements `divisor` and then dereferences it. Since `divisor` initially points at the space allocated for one `unsigned int`, decrementing it results in an invalid pointer, and the behavior of that and of dereferencing it is not defined.

What was intended here was `(*divisor)--` or `--*divisor`, both of which dereference `divisor` and then decrement the `unsigned int` it points to.

Comment: A great answer, illustrating the importance of remaining aware of operator precedence when working with pointers you intend to change:  Are you changing the pointer, or what it points to?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code in C. It uses fuction recursion and Euclid's theorem to find the HCF of two integers:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hcf(int x, int y)
{
int c = x % y;
if (c == 0)
{
    printf("%d", y);
}
else
{
    hcf(y, c);
}
}
void main()
{
int a, b;
printf("GIVE INPUTS:: \n");
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
int max, min;
if (a >= b)
{
    max = a;
    min = b;
}
else
{
    max = b;
    min = a;
}

hcf(max, min);
}
```